# How to organize or reuse Redux shouldfetch* action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the redux [document](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.md#action-creators-and-constants), they provide an action method to prevent re-fetch existing data.

Like this:

```
function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
    subreddit,
    posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}

function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
    return fetch(`http://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then(req => req.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
  }
}

function shouldFetchPosts(state, subreddit) {
  const posts = state.postsBySubreddit[subreddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  } else if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  } else {
    return posts.didInvalidate
  }
}

export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
}
```

I know the method can prevent fetch again.

However, if I have more api, I need to write more functions to judge fetch situation.

This way make my code more complicated and hard to maintain.

Does anyone have suggestion to combine the `shouldfetch*IfNeeded / shouldFetch* / fetch*` to make it more reusabe?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this conf talk by Sebastian Markbage (one of the React devs): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4anAwXYqLG8

The essential message is don't abstract for the purpose of avoiding repetitive code, unless there's a potential for avoiding bugs.

In this case the `shouldUpdate` type function is really quite simple - it's a pure function, which takes the store state, and does a simple check to see if the state is valid, and returns a boolean.

There really isn't abstraction to be had there in my opinion. You could perhaps assume that all your async state will have this shape:

`state.<asnycPartOfState>.isFetching` and `state.<asnycPartOfState>.didInvalidate`.

But trying to abstract this away doesn't seem to serve much purpose, and limits the flexibility of your API (convention over configuration). While I think convention is sometimes good, in this case I don't think it'll provide much value.

What's more is sometimes your state will be an array  like`postsBySubreddit[<userID>]`, and sometimes it will just be a single object like `user`. Then again it could also need to be `_.findWhere(postsBySubreddit, { _id: <someID> })`, or maybe even `_.findWhere(postsBySubreddit, { _id: <someID>, active_user: true })`.

In this case I think your better off making your code easy to follow and read by avoiding abstraction, until you find you need it.